# Could homeless people unionize? How?

Tags: civil-rights, social-welfare, housing, citizen-activism

How do people form unions? What steps/processes/protocols/organizational structures are involved? Or do they vary from union to union?

Could homeless people unionize, so as to engage in collective bargaining, for their rights, living conditions, etc.? How?

Comment: Do you equal homelessness with joblessness? If not, a home may not exclude one from being in a union. If yes, unions typically negotiate better salaries with for example strikes but without a job there are no salaries or employers to bargain with. Did you maybe mean political parties, lobby groups or activism for increased social welfare?

Comment: I don't think the question is clear. Especially the "collective bargaining" should be fleshed out more. What exactly do you have in mind that these "unions" should do or achieve?

Comment: Voting to close - This Q is overly broad. You should narrow it down by asking about a specific country, for example.

Comment: Fiction, but "The Beggars' Strike": https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/857005

Comment: The vast majority of the the homeless you see on the street are alcoholics, drug addicts or mentally disabled. Not exactly a group with great cognitive capabilities for any sort of organization.

Comment: @JonathanReez is "vast majority" backed up by data or just the way you look at them?

Comment: @uhoh it’s backed by data from every city, at least in America. Again, I’m talking about the _visible_ homeless.

Answer (score 26):

Unions are generally *trade* unions: workers who organize to bargain with an industry for better working conditions and benefits by withholding trade-related labor. Homelessness is not a trade, and there is no industry that they could withhold their labor *from*. I suppose one could image some sort of Dickens-esque panhandlers organization, but that would be more like an organized crime group than a proper union.

On the other hand, the homeless *could* organize as a political interest group, staging protests, demonstrations, sit-ins, or other forms of civil disobedience in order to demand governmental action or seek better treatment from local businesses. This would be more on the model of the Civil Rights actions of the '60s, and Cesar Chavez attempted something like it with itinerant farm workers.

Comment: Yeah, such an organization could be called an "advocacy group" or "political action committee (PAC)", but a "union" is assumed to be a group of *workers*.

Comment: @dan04, it's true in general that a "union" strongly implies a *trade union*, but there are other common kinds, like tenants unions, credit unions, and so on.

Comment: Downvoted because you seem to think that begging is a crime.

Comment: Begging itself can be a crime (it just depends on the law, not whether I think it should be, except possibly in the voting booth). What the author means, is: there are racketeering operations that control areas where begging is more lucrative. The practices range from taking a cut, enforced by violence to outright forcing people, sometimes kids, to spend time begging. I would think that such practices are illegal practically everywhere.

Comment: @ccprog That was my initial reaction too. But I guess it refers specifically to the "Dickens-esque panhandlers union", which I suppose would be the pickpocketing racket in Oliver Twist. But this could definitely benefit from a clarification.

Comment: @jkej An aside on literary references: As a German, I don't think so much of DIckens, but of Bertolt Brecht's Threepenny Opera and the _Beggar's Friends_ organization of Mr. Peachum...what I insist on is that a self-organization of the homeless has **absolutely no reason** to turn to "racketeering" (which, by the way, is a specifically American term that does not exist in other languages and mostly does not translate directly to crimes in other jurisdictions.) The obvious form for the homeless to gain bargaining power is squatting.

Comment: @ccprog: I didn't mean to imply begging was a crime; I meant to suggest that a panhandlers 'union' would be an unregulated or underground monopoly over resources (e.g., panhandling spots, off-the-books labor, charity donations, etc). There's no good word for that in English except for 'mob' or 'racket'. The Dickens reference was meant to soften that a bit (because Dickens took that in a light-hearted way) but I guess that didn't work. At any rate, it's different from a union proper because a union controls *labor* not *resources*.  I'll think about revisions…

Answer (score 10):

> How do people form unions?

That is dependent on the jurisdiction and can differ in the extreme. In Germany, the constitutional right to form unions is interpreted as meaning that almost any form of law that regulates unions is considered unconstitutional. In France the Labor Code contains pages and pages of articles describing how an organisation must be structured to be considered a union. (On the other hand, in Germany strikes are only allowed in order to negotiate employment conditions, while French unions regularily take part in all sorts of political disputes, up to calling for general strikes.)

But that was a side question.

> Could homeless people unionize, so as to engage in collective bargaining?

In the 1990s, there was a movement for homeless to [publish newspapers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_newspaper) and to sell them in the street. The idea was to inform the public about the issues surrounding homelessness, and to give the homeless street sellers a legitimate income. (Some of these magazines still exist, I think.)

It was was one of the most successfull and long-lasting **self-organizations** of homeless people (in contrast to charities) I can remember. But while it served to raise awareness, it lacked the component of bargaining and thus forcing some counterpart to negotiate.

Looking from a theoretical standpoint, there seems to be a *natural* way to get bargaining power about what really matters for a homeless person: squatting.

I know of a few examples where squatting was organized in such a way as to make it a public and political issue. Recently, in Berlin a large appartment block ([Haabersathstraße 40-48](https://taz.de/Erfolgreiche-Besetzung-in-Berlin/!5822941/)) was occupied by organized homeless, and the owner, who had tried to leave the house empty in a speculative scheme, was forced to accept at least temporary lease contracts with the occupiers. Since then, he has tried to get rid of them again. So far, courts have both conceded his right to evict them at the end of the lease, but also [blocked him](https://www.labournet.de/interventionen/wipo-gegenwehr/antikap/commons/die-haeuser-denen-die-sie-brauchen-obdachlose-menschen-besetzen-das-papageienhaus-in-berlin-mitte/) from enforcing that title.

So why is that not a widespread and generally accepted strategy?

- For squatting, there needs to be vacant housing. There are times and places where this might be true, but in an overcrowded city where the poor are already forced into slums, it is not a realistic perspective.
- Capitalist societies are good at protecting the rights of house owners. While the right to fight for better working conditions is accepted by most countries, the right to fight for a home is not. Beating unwilling workers on strike to get them back to work is considered illegal. Forcibly dragging squatters out of their housing and demolishing it afterwards is common police practice in a lot of places.

A squatters organisation apparently lacks a long-term benefit. As soon as the former homeless has housing he/she will loose the existential interest in the broader issue and will concentrate on *remaining* in the housing. In Berlin in the 1970s/80s, squatting was a widespread and successfull movement (not because of widespread homelessness, but because there were so many empty appartments). But then the dust settled, some squats turned into permanent tenant relations, in other cases the squatters even bought the houses they had occupied, and the former activists left the movement. They joined [tenants unions](https://www.bmgev.de/) instead that would concentrate on protecting their lease conditions.

Compare that to the workers situation, where unions tend to concentrate on working conditions and payment and not care much about the interests of the unemployed.

Comment: I'm surprised you say they won in Habersaathstraße. You know what happened in Liebigstraße 34, and in Køpi Wagenplatz? Lots and lots of violence, initiated by the government, under the control of the government.